# Django models filter by one to one model field

Tags: django, django-models

Imagine I have those two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(
        to=A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False
    )
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And I want a queryset of B model to be filtered by the a.name and location,

like this:

```
select * from B join A
on B.a.pk = A.pk
where A.name="name" and B.location="location";
```

I tried this but it gives an error:

```py
 query=B.objects.filter(a.name=name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation carefully. U can access related fields with double underscore. So in your case dat will be:

```
query=B.objects.filter(a__name='name', location='location')
```